# convert event data to timeseries

Tags: sql, postgresql, events, time-series, grafana

I have a table like

```
CODE  | start      | end
A     | 2023-03-03 |2023-03-04
A     | 2023-03-07 |2023-03-09 
B     | 2023-03-03 |2023-03-06
C     | 2023-03-02 | "null"
```

Where

- code is the event code,
- start when the event activate
- end when the event recover, it can also be empty this means event has not recovered yet

With an sql query (possibly to be executable in Postgres), I want to convert into a timeseries, e.g., given the event code A
I get something like

```
2023-03-03 1 
2023-03-06 0 
2023-03-07 1
2023-03-09 0
```

where 1 is for the activation, 0 is for the recovery
it is something like Select timestamp, value from timeseries where code = ? (in the example code is A)

Comment: why the second date is *2023-03-06* and not *2023-03-04* ?

Comment: What exactly and how do plan to visualize with this query? Shouldn't your query return rows for every day?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL to combine 2 queries against the table, one query picking up the start times (and calling this event_date) and a second picking up the end time (and also mapping that to event_date).

The following returns the results you requested (assuming, per the other comment, that the March 6, 2023 date is a typo and should be March 4, like in your original table):

```
-- create the original table
create table event_log (code varchar, start_date date, end_date date);
    
-- populate it with data
    insert into event_log values ('A', '2023-03-03'::date, '2023-03-04'::date);
    insert into event_log values ('A', '2023-03-07'::date, '2023-03-09'::date);
    insert into event_log values ('B', '2023-03-03'::date, '2023-03-06'::date);
    insert into event_log values ('C', '2023-03-02'::date, null);
    
-- use union all to retrieve 2 rows for each event
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT code, start_date as event_date, 1 as activation
        FROM event_log
        UNION ALL
        SELECT code, end_date as event_date, 0 as activation
        FROM event_log
        WHERE end_date IS NOT NULL
    ) q 
    WHERE code = 'A'
    ORDER BY event_date;
```

I would wrap the main part of that query up as a view, so you can query the data as needed without worrying about the details.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW event_stream AS
    SELECT code, start_date as event_date, 1 as activation
        FROM event_log
    UNION ALL
    SELECT code, end_date as event_date, 0 as activation
        FROM event_log
        WHERE end_date IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY event_date, code, activation desc;
```

Then to retrieve the data would query the view, like so:

```
select * 
from event_stream
where code='A';
```